# Looking for a SAML SSO certification

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We are currently implementing SAML2 SP lite profile for our SAAS offering and we are looking for a way to certify our implementation.

I already did some research and learned about the Kantara Initiative ( http://kantarainitiative.org/wordpress/programs/iop-certification/ ). Anyone has some feedback on the interoperability events ?

I also ended up on http://www.pingidentity.com/ and was wondering is anyone has any feedback on their "ping certified" program.

Comment: I have heard of ping but not kantara. OKTA is another leader in the space that has partner programs.